# Django 2 desde ListView acceso a dos models

Tags: django

Quiero desde una Clase ListView acceder a dos modelos relacionados.
models.py

```
class MdCategoria(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, # obligatoria la longitud
        verbose_name='Nombre',
    )
class MdEntrada(models.Model):  
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(
        MdCategoria,
        verbose_name='Categorías', # para que pueda elegir la categoria
    )
```

Con Un ListView quiero acceder a los datos de MdEntrada y sus correspondientes de MdCategoria. view.py

```
class VwCategoria(BaseView, ListView):
    template_name = 'ap_blog/categoria.html'
    model = MdEntrada
```

¿ Cómo debo indicar el query de acceso a MdCategoria desde VwCategoria ?
Después, ¿ qué template tags necesito para acceder a MdCategoria desde categoría.html ?

Comment: No entiendo muy bien el objetivo de hacer lo que quieres hacer pero hay un método llamado `get_queryset` dentro de `ListView` que te permite devolver un query de forma personalizada. Mira [aquí](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.1/django.views.generic.list/ListView/#get_queryset)

Answer (score 0):

Fijate en este ejemplo:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    pass

class Entry(..):
    blog = Blog(..)
```

entries = b.entry_set.all()

El objeto _set  está disponible cuando [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) no se especifica .

Answer (score 0):

Tengo bastante rato sin tocar Django, espero que mi respuesta pueda guiarte más de lo que te confunda.

Al momento de usar "*Vistas Basadas en Clases*" (o *CBV* por sus ciclas en inglés), cuentas con una lista de métodos que puedes extender y usar de acuerdo a tus necesidades, tal como te comenté hay uno llamado `get_queryset` y entre otros, lo importante es saber cuando se llama cada método dentro del hook de la clase. En [éste](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.1/django.views.generic.list/ListView/) enlace tienes una página donde describe cada método de cada clase de django para las *CBV*.

Ahora, obtener el query es sencillo, simplemente toma el nombre que le diste en tu definición del modelo:

```
from .models import MdEntrada, MdCategoria  # relativo a donde estén tus modelos
# Para obtener las categorías de una entrada específica, es así
MdEntrada.objects.first().categories.all()
# También puedes hacer la consulta al contrario, como te explicaron en otra respuesta, es decir, a partir de una categoría obtener las entradas asociadas
MdCategoria.objects.first().mdentrada_set.all()
```

Ahora, esto como se acopla en tu Vista? leyendo en la página que te mostré, hay un método llamado: `get_context_data` el cual es el encargado de pasarle los datos a tu template, y lo hace por medio de la key: `object_list` la cual contiene la lista de tus objetos.

La pregunta, ¿Cómo accedo desde el template? la respuesta es, tal cual como lo harías en python normal, obvio que con los templatetags, así:

```
{% for entrada in object_list %}
  <p>{{ entrada.id }}</p>
  {% for categoria in entrada.categories.all %}
     <li>{{ categoria.name }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Espero haberte ayudado, y cualquier duda que tengas, no dudes en comentarme